# Pass var form Worksheet to Workbook in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have in my worksheet code like

```
   Public TmpSave As Range

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    TmpSave = Target
    .
    .
    .

End Sub
```

And in my Workbook i want to do something with the last selected Target like

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _Cancel As Boolean)
        TmpSave.Interior.ColorIndex = 18
End Sub
```

Is there a way to archive this? I googled, but i didnt really found a solution, im sorry if this question already exists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
Set TmpSave = Target
```

in the worksheet and when referring to the variable you need to qualify it as a member of the worksheet using the worksheet code name:

```
Sheet1.TmpSave.Interior.ColorIndex = 18
```

for example. You can also move the variable declaration to a normal module and then you can just refer to TmpSave.